# Implementing a clickable ShareThis button

Tags: php, wordpress, sharethis

I've been working on this code to implement a clickable "Share" button for ShareThis, e.g. instead of code that will pop-up the ShareThis window when the user hovers over the button.  The key to make it work is the onmouseover:false setting:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var object = SHARETHIS.addEntry({
        title: "<?php the_title(); ?>",
        url: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"},
            {button:false,onmouseover:false});

    document.write('<span id="<?php the_title(); ?>"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Share</a></span>');

    var element = document.getElementById("<?php the_title(); ?>");
    object.attachButton(element);

</script>
```

The problem is that the onmouseover:false setting causes the close button (X) to stop working in the popup window (the various ShareThis controls all work).  Is there any kind of workaround to get that functionality working again?

Comment: Please change your script tags --<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  TO --> <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Ok, done (problem still exists though).

Comment: good man it was just a reminder to use proper structure :) now check my answer, quotes are not properly balanced i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added popup:true to the property list, like this:

```
var object = SHARETHIS.addEntry({
    title: "<?php the_title(); ?>",
    url: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"},
        {button:false,onmouseover:false,popup:true});
```

The causes the nice ShareThis popup box to appear within a completely separate window.  It's not quite as elegant, but it works.  I'll leave this for a couple of days, if no one else has a suggestion to re-enable the close button on the popup then I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code ---

```
var object = SHARETHIS.addEntry({
        title: "<?php the_title(); ?>",
        url: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"},  <----
            {button:false,onmouseover:false <----
});
```

quotes are not balanced

Comment: I think it's ok, the quotes are for the title and url elements, and the brackets are balanced for the two parameters for the addEntry call.

Comment: @Kevin my bad bro im talking about this--" } "

Comment: Sorry I don't see the problem, is it just the formatting you are concerned about?  There are two sets of brackets, one around each of the two parameters to the addEntry call.

Comment: @Kevin checked your code from this --- <script type="text/javascript">
//Create your sharelet with desired properties and set button element to false
var object = SHARETHIS.addEntry({
title:"<?php the_title(); ?>",
summary: 'Sharing is good for the soul.'},
{button:false});
//Output your customized button
document.write('<span id="share"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="/my_share_icon.gif" />Share!</a></span>');




//Tie customized button to ShareThis button functionality.
var element = document.getElementById("share");
object.attachButton(element);
</script>   and yes its all ok